# How to say "does this make a difference?" more formally?

Tags: formal-language, formality

> [Some fact about our component.] Does this **make a difference** for inclusion in the OtherCompany App Store?

Sounds not as formal as I would like a business email to be. It's passable, I think, but I don't like it. One alternative I've been able to come up with is this:

> [Some fact about our component.] Does this **matter** for inclusion in the OtherCompany App Store?

But it's not very different.

How could one say this in a business email where I do not know the other party personally?

Comment: A little more context would help - it's easier if we're sure what your intended meaning actually is, and it's not entirely clear from just that sentence. It doesn't need to be the bit you omitted - I can see why you would miss that out. But not knowing what *inclusion* in the product involves makes it a little harder. I mean, it matters whether *inclusion* is the right choice, rather than *incorporation* or *use* or similar.

Comment: @SamBC - Agreed. I don’t think it really matters much if we use _matters_ or _makes a difference_. But “for inclusion in your product” reads quite awkwardly.

Comment: Updated as requested. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes, much more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is to ask about **relevance**.

> [Information]. **Is this relevant to** inclusion in the OtherCompany AppStore?

It's a phrase that is more suited to a formal register than an informal one, and it's asking if the information is in any way of interest as regards inclusion in the AppStore in question.

Your original version doesn't seem informal, however, as much as it is subtly 'wrong' to native eyes/ears. Making a difference *for* inclusion just doesn't work, though I can't put my finger on why.

However you phrase it, you might potentially be better of specifically asking about the inclusion of this app itself - assuming you are talking about a specific app. If it's a component you are trying to market to app authors, you might specify that you are referring to the inclusion of apps that make use of it. So that could be:

> Is this relevant to **possible inclusion of** [name of app] in the OtherCompany AppStore?

or:

> Is this relevant to **inclusion of apps that make use of** [name of component] in the OtherCompany AppStore?

Comment: I see you were downvoted. I found this answer the most helpful so far and was planning to accept it if no further answers appear, but a downvote makes me wonder if there is something inaccurate about it. It would be nice if the downvoter could explain their reason.

Comment: @Luc: I'd quite appreciate that as well. I've had a little rash of downvotes without comments lately.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this information (more) relevant for inclusion in your product?

or (depending on intention):

> Is this information (more) relevant for using the component in your product?